# How do I fix a Java Priority-Queue to correctly sort by a specific property?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I have a Java PriorityQueue for sorting objects from a specific class I made called Node. I want it to sort the Nodes by their getData() method. I tried the following code (using a comparator), but it did not work. When I called the priority queue's "poll" method, it did not return the lowest results first, but in a seemingly random order. How do I fix it? Thanks!

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(hm.size(),
        new Comparator<Node>( ) {
            // override the compare method
            public int compare(Node i, Node j) {
                if (i.getData()<j.getData()){
                                        return i.getData(); //It should sort by the Node's getData method.
                                    }
                                    return j.getData();
```

Comment: "Did not work" what do you mean? What was your input and output, and what was the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the compare method:

```
public int compare(Node i, Node j) {
  return i.getData() - j.getData()
}
```

This will follow requirements of compare method to return value less, equal or more than zero depending on comparison result.

Comment: From OOP prospective - yes, however I meant something along "in code you have provided change content of compare method".

Comment: By the way, it's vulnerable to integer overflow.

Answer (score 8):

A [comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) needs to return -1 (a negative number), 0 or +1 (a positive number) depending on whether the first operand is less-than, equal-to or greater-than the second operand.  You are returning the data itself which won't do what you want.